# VSCode - open file in cwd

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My VS code debug folder is:
`C:\Users\EML\Python Code`

and the file I am working with is in:
`C:\Users\EML\Python Code\Boggle`
In the same folder I have the file `en-dict.txt` but I get this error message

```
with open("en-dict.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'en-dict.txt'
```

This is my launch.json settings in VS Code:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
```

I have looked at many StackOverflow answers and none have helped me yet.

Comment: What do you mean "debug folder"? And what folder have you opened in VS Code (it should be `C:\Users\EML\Python Code\Boggle` based on how your code is written).

Comment: By debug I mean I have opened VS code in ```C:\Users\EML\Python Code```

Answer (score 2):

if you set your launch as:

```
{
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": ""
        }
```

it will invoke the python in the same directory where it is located.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this but am still getting the same error message

Answer (score 1):

Try opening `C:\Users\EML\Python Code\Boggle` in VS Code instead of `C:\Users\EML\Python Code` as that will implicitly make the working directory be what you're expecting. Otherwise you have to be very careful about what file you have open when you launch the debugger to make sure that `${fileDirname}` gets set appropriately. Otherwise you can hard-code the working directory in your `launch.json`.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only workaround I have managed to achieve. I was hoping there was a way around this, rather than having to manually change the folder for each new project. Shame